# Why the git repository size stays the same after migration to LFS

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have a git repository with a huge (2.5GB) file inside one of the folders. As there have been some versions before (actually, different files, the old one has been always deleted and new one added in a commit), the size of the repository on the disk is ~12.5GB (`du -sm repository`).

I have converted the repository to LFS using `git lfs migrate import --everything --include="big-file-folder/**"` - this step caused the repository size to grow to ~17GB on the local disc (where I did the migration). When I did `git push --force` to a remote bitbucket and then cloned the repository again, the freshly cloned one has ~15GB.

Then I found out there is a `git lfs prune` command, but when I run it on the migrated repository, it only shrinks to pre-migration size of ~12.5GB, not to ~3GB what I would expect (the 2.5GB for one version of the big file, plus ~0.5GB for the rest of the repository content).

It looks like the 5 previous versions of the big file are still in the repository, which is not what I have expected.

Note: I am using git-lfs 2.13, we have an old bitbucket that does not support the newer 3.0.

Comment: git without LFS is decentralized meaning that all clones are complete copies of the repository and its history. Moving some files to LFS does not change what is already in the history of the repository, it only affect what will happen next time the file is modified

Comment: @TheIceBear I've got the impression that when I use `--everything` (and without `--no-rewrite`), even the local history will be changed, i.e. the specified files in the history will be replaced with LFS pointers.

Comment: Git, by default, saves stuff for at least 30 and typically at least 90 days, and even in extreme cases, for at least 14 days. To find out the "real" size, clone the repository. If that's what you expect, you can simply move the existing large clone out of the way, move the small clone into place, and work. Once it's sufficiently proven you can remove the old clone. If you want to dig deeper, look at the `git filter-branch` documentation and its "checklist for shrinking a repository".

Comment: Thank you @torek, that explains it. Would you mind to add this as an answer so I can mark it a correct?

Comment: I don't actually *use* Git-LFS so I wasn't able to test it. I'm still not sure I have all the nitty details right. You might want to test this thoroughly, then self-answer it.